# Want to create a wearable app for my existing Eclipse App

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

I have a project made with **eclipse** and I want to create a wearable app for that project. Can you please help me with this.

It's very easy to create a wearable app for an existing **android studio** project but in *eclipse*, I don't know how to start.

Comment: Eclipse is no longer officially supported., you really should switch to Android Studio. Android Studio can import Eclipse projects and convert them appropriately: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html#migrate-eclipse

Comment: simplest and most correct is stop using eclipse. Soon there will be a moment when noone will know what is eclipse at all

Comment: @Karakuri I am working with android studio since the last 1year but the project for which I am talking about is an older one and I have tried a lot to convert it into android studio but it looks like a nightmare for me because it has so many old libraries so could not able to convert it so please is there any way in eclipse?

Comment: None that I know of. There is nothing about Android Studio that prevents you from using those libraries. It would probably be to your benefit to convert that project anyway because, if those libraries are as old as you say, then you ought to update them to more recent versions.

Comment: Yaa you are absolutely correct, I also converted many eclipse project to android studio but in this project, I am just facing an error called **Enter a value for workspace path src/test/java** and I have also tried to  solve this error but could not able to do that...:(

Comment: You might want to check [How to develop and package Android Wear App using Eclipse](https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d#.7liso2sdz) wherein it gives step by step on how to setup and package an Android Wear app using Eclipse.

Comment: I have gone through it already but the procedure did not work for me @Teyam